# Multiple file upload validation- Restrict selection of same file twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, validation

I want to restrict selection of same file twice from a multiple upload field in my form.

I have made following codes to select/deselect/re-select files from the same input field.

```
<input type="file" name="attachment" id="attachment" multiple>
<script type="text/javascript">
fileList = [];
$("#attachment").fileupload({
    sequentialUploads : true,
    change : function(e, data) {
        for ( var i = 0; i < data.files.length; i++) {
            //display files and clear options
            fileList.push(data.files[i]);
        }
        return false;
    }
});
</script>
```

Can anyone tell me if there any way to get the path of the selected file from input filed so that I can compare it with the previous selected files and validate my form?

Comment: if you are selecting multiple files at same time, then file cannot get repeated because you wont have same file twice in a folder and if you are having multiple browse fields, then keep comparing the names of files using files['name'] or something like that

Comment: I have single input field and I am allowing to select files again by storing the previous files in one list.

Comment: then you should just compare for the file name in the file list[]

Comment: I need to compare file path, as it wont work if I wish to attach two files with same name but different directory.

Comment: @ShreyasDave Please do a search on Stackoverflow or Google regarding access to the full path of a file client-side.  You will see that this is not available in most cases.

Comment: thats not possible to do, because it is a kind of privacy issue, you cannot keep track of whole paths

Answer (score 0):

you cant get real file path from browser. for security reason browser don't allow to give you real path of files. so you can't compare file path for duplicate file. however if this is necessary for you can compare file by using hashcode() method. here are same discussion thread on https://drupal.org/node/1077598